# How do I print to the mmio display in Mips

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

```
   .data

str1:    .byte '1'

    .text 

    lw $a0, str1
    lui $t0, 0xffff #ffff0000
    sw $a0, 12($t0) #data
```

I want to print 1 to the mmio display in mips, but this is not working does anyone know why

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: it doesnt output anything to the mmio display, is it suppose to?

Comment: First you should open the _Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator_ and click _Connect to MIPS_ (you didn't mention if you've done this). Also, before you write to `0xffff000c` you should poll the transmitter control register (address `0xffff0008`) until the `ready` bit is set (bit 0).